# MVC 4 action link popup box confirmation for delete?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

What's the best way to perform a confirmation pop out when click the actionlink to perform a delete? Currently when i press the delete action link, it will straight delete. Anyway to perform a pop out confirmation box to delete?
Thanks!

My View:

```
  <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "SURV_Question_Delete", "SURV_Question", new { Question_ID = Model[i].Question_ID }, null)
  </td>
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult SURV_Question_Delete(int Question_ID)
        {

            var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model.ToList()
                        where r.Qext_Question_ID == Question_ID
                        select r;

            foreach(var item in query)
            { 
                db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model.Remove(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("SURV_Main_Edit", "SURV_Main", new { id = surveyId });
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, a delete action should not be a GET, it should be a POST. Use javascript/jquery to handle the `.click()` event (or more correctly the `.submit()` event of the form) and display an confirm/popup and based on the return value, cancel the submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke any code sample for me to easy refer? Thanks.

Comment: check anser might help you in what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, add online on link which call javascript function for confirmation.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "SURV_Question_Delete", "SURV_Question",
 new { Question_ID = Model[i].Question_ID, onclick = "return 
                                            DeleteConfirm()" }, null)


 function DeleteConfirm() 
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete record"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;        
    }
```

---

you can also try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "SURV_Question_Delete", "SURV_Question",
     new { Question_ID = Model[i].Question_ID,  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"},null);
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple & Clean.

Comment: Simple, yes. Clean, NO! A link is a GET, GET should not be used to modify data as already stated http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your delete action should be a POST, not a GET. Your modifying data and do not want this added to the browser history, or allow the url to be entered in the address bar (the item may have already been deleted)

Change your html to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SURV_Question_Delete", "SURV_Question", new { Question_ID = Model[i].Question_ID }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="delete" />
}
```

and decorate the method with the `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attributes.

Then add a script

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  // Modify the following to use you jquery-ui-dialog, but for testing purposes
  if (!confirm("Are you sure want to delete record") { 
    return false; // cancel the submit if the user clicked the Cancel button
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You also can do the following, which will show the confirm box with
>   the value you want to delete, which is more perfect in case of
>   deleting.

```
  
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Subject", "DeleteSubject", "Subjects", new { SubjectId = _item.SubjectMsId },
                            new { onClick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to Delete the Subject : "+
                                @_item.SubjectName+" ?')" })
```